# How many emails one should receive if mentioned multiple times in cc

Tags: email

I am sending auto generated emails in an application. Somehow, during the testing phase in the email generated from system we have the same person mentioned in CC multiple times.

For example:

To: user1@example.com

CC: user1@example.com,user1@example.com

body: some text here.

---

**Expectation:** Now client is expecting to receive three emails.

**Actual:** Client is receiving one email.

1. Please advice how many emails should client receive?
2. Are there any rules defined for emails like above that person mentioned multiple times will receive only one email.

   3. Does that depend on the mail client like outlook, gmail etc being used that how many emails will be received.
   4. Does that depend on the SMTP settings that in such cases how many emails will be sent.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How many did you receive when you tested this?

Comment: Only one email.

Comment: Is there any reason that a user would receive more when you cc:d them repeatedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SMTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821):

> When the same message is sent to multiple recipients the SMTP
> encourages the transmission of only one copy of the data for all the
> recipients at the same destination host.

It’s up to the implementers of SMTP at both sending and receiving ends how to handle duplicate recipients, but de-duplicating seems like a fundamental and obvious optimisation for an implementation. I’ve never seen an implementation that doesn’t de-duplicate in this case.

Comment: Thanks sasfron for your efforts. It is really helpful and solves my problem.